# Printing a field in a Drupal 6 template

Tags: php, drupal

I believe the currently accepted form for printing a field in a Drupal 7 template is `print render($content['field_name_here']);`

However, I believe this was changed from something else in Drupal 6, and I cannot find documentation - how do I print a particular field value in a Drupal 6 template?

Comment: It depends - what template?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.  Are you looking for the drupal_render function?

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6

Answer (score 0):

You can always print your fields from the $node variable (assuming this is a template for a type of content). Typically, it would be structured:

```
<?php print $node->your_field_name[0]['value']; ?>
```

You can see what variables are all available by simply doing a:

```
<?php print_r ($node); ?>
```

and looking at the output.